# How to vary binwidth inside ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'am doing histogram with ggplot.

```
p <- ggplot(TotCalc, aes(x=x,y=100*(..count../sum(..count..)))) + 
    xlab(xlabel) + ylab(ylabel) +
    geom_histogram(colour = "darkblue", fill = "white", binwidth=500)
```

my x is between 2 and 6580 and I have 2600 data.

I want to plot one histogram with different `binwidth`. Is it possible?

For example, I want to have 8 bars, with width like this:

```
c(180,100,110,160,200,250,1000,3000)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

how about using breaks?

```
x <- rnorm(100)
ggplot(NULL, aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = c(-5, -2, 0, 5), 
  position = "identity", colour = "black", fill = "white")
```

P.S. Please don't cross post without explicit notification.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `breaks` and `position="dodge"`

eg:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=hp))+geom_histogram(breaks=c(50,100,200,350),position="dodge")
```

Don't have your data, but for your example:

```
p <- ggplot(TotCalc, aes(x=x,y=100*(..count../sum(..count..)))) +
     xlab(xlabel) + ylab(ylabel) +
    geom_histogram(colour = "darkblue", fill = "white", breaks=cumsum(c(180,100,110,160,200,250,1000,3000)), position="dodge")
```